# Map putall equivalent method in typescript Map

Tags: typescript

Problem Statement: Wanted to combine Map B to Map A in typescript without changing reference of Map A

Doing below changes the reference of first Map

```
const MapA: Map<string, string> = new Map([...MapA, ...MapB]);
```

I tried searching, but couldn't find any equivalent method on typescript to put all entries of one map

Comment: What is `MapA` and `MapB`?  How does it "change reference of Map A"? Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/wgXVBN) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: Btw there is no such method, so you'd have to do something else, like use a `.forEach()` on `MapB` like [this code](https://tsplay.dev/WYva2w).  But without a [mre] that defines both `MapA` and `MapB` and details what you expect the outcome to be, I can't really test it.